# Draw on Image loaded inside HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, html5-canvas

I have a HTML canvas in Ionic app.

```
 <canvas id="canvas" color="{{ color }}" width="800" height="600" style="position:relative;"></canvas>
```

In this canvas, I am loading an image. Below is the code from controller

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = $stateParams.imageId;

        img.onload = function() {
           context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }
```

After the image is loaded, users need the ability to write on the image and circle/highlight certain areas of the image.

Doesn't HTML canvas provide this feature by default? Right now I am not able to annotate anything on the image. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement this yourself.

You can do it by hooking into the mouse click / move events. using your 2d context, draw small rectangle at the mouse's current position if the most moves and the left mouse button is down.

The effect is similar to a Windows paint pencil tool. Here's a simple example.

```html
<html>

<head>
<style>
 canvas{
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>

<script>
 var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 
 var isMouseDown = false;
 
 canvas.onmousedown = function(e){
  isMouseDown = true;
 }
 
 canvas.onmouseup = function(e){
  isMouseDown = false;
 }
 
 canvas.onmousemove = function(e){
 
  if(isMouseDown === false){
   return;
  }
 
  var canvasPosition = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
 
  var x = e.clientX - canvasPosition.left;
  var y = e.clientY - canvasPosition.top;
  
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 2, 2);
 };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would the mouse click events work on Ionic, when the app is running on device like iPhone.

Comment: If I use an attribute called "autogram" in my canvas tag, then drawing works by default, provided it is a blank canvas. However, when I load image on the canvas then autogram does not have any impact.

<canvas autogram color="{{ color }}"></canvas>

Comment: "autogram" is not part of the html5 canvas element. If you are using some library you should be sure to make it apparent in your question.

Comment: `MouseEvent.x` is still in draft and is not supported by all UAs (FF), You should still prefer its long version `MouseEvent.clientX`.

Comment: Thank you. The code works perfectly on Desktop but not in iPad. I added the $ionicGesture to the controller but it did not help. Looks like I am not calling $ionicGesture correctly  ----> 
$ionicGesture.on('dragstart', onmousedown, canvas);
    $ionicGesture.on('drag', onmousemove, canvas);
    $ionicGesture.on('dragend', onmouseup, canvas);

Comment: Sorry but I have no expertise in this ionic thing, you need to consult with their forum or something.